# Echo appending to a text file

Tags: batch-file, output, echo, special-characters

So, when I'm echoing text from a batch file to a text file, I can escape the special characters without issue. However, when I echo a certain character combination, I can't seem to find a way around the fact that it is just echoing to the screen and not to the file.

Here's what works...

```
echo firsttest^=uncpath>>test.txt
echo [secondtest]>>test.txt
```

Here's what doesn't work...

```
echo thirdtest^=1>>test.txt
echo fourthtest^=2>>test.txt
```

I've tried escaping one and both of the arrow characters, but still no-go.

Any advice? I'm sure it has to do with the standard redirection of console output using the "1>" and the "2>", but just don't know how to get around that.

Thanx.

Comment: `echo thirdtest^=1 >>test.txt`, note the white space.

Comment: @jwdonahue then the space will be redirected too (usually unwanted). The shown example looks like a sort of INI or CFG file, where reading back the values (with space) will cause harm or at least irritation.

Comment: @Stephan, yup, haven't had my caffeine fix yet.

Comment: @user3208239, please go back to all of your previous questions and accept answers to your questions.  That is the main purpose of StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. There are two main concepts to work around it:

```
(echo thirdtest=1)>>test.txt
(echo fourthtest=2)>>test.txt
```

and

```
>>test.txt echo thirdtest=1
>>test.txt echo fourthtest=2
```

(Note: `=` isn't one of the special characters that need escaping)

Where in the line you put your redirection doesn't matter, as running with `echo on` shows. (if you enjoy to get confused, enter `echo hello>file.txt world`, followed by `type file.txt`)

Another note: if you `echo` several lines, it's faster to:

```
(
  echo first line
  echo second line
  echo third line
)>>test.txt
```

(reason: needs only one disk access (read/modify/write) instead of doing the same  for each single line) You won't notice it with just three lines, but think of writing hundreds of lines (for example in a loop). Time savings will be huge.

Comment: Or you can just add a space between the digit and the redirect.

Comment: You should add the point that the parentheses allow for white space to be included in the echo output.

Comment: @jwdonahue Adding a space between the digit and the redirect will redirect the space too (usually unwanted). The parantheses allow for white space **not** to be included in the echo output.

Comment: Should have worded that differently. The parentheses give you more control, whether white space is included in the output.